# How to write SQLite query in android to show the partial matching names?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to write an SQLite statement to show all the movie names starting with the word *"The"*. but I am unable to get the result. I am getting empty result.

My Implemented Query is:

```
Curcor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MYMOVIES WHERE NAME='%"+query+"%';", null);
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if this was a typo, but that should be `Cursor` not, `Curcor`.

The [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), is by far, detailed.

but for the record, `rawQuery` is designed to prevent string concatenation by matching every `?` with the relevant string parameter in the accompanying array that is passed to the function itself.

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MYMOVIES WHERE NAME LIKE ?", new String[]{ query } );
```

Be sure query contains a `%` at end of the string, i.e. `The%`.

Comment: Wouldn't `%The%` find any occurrence of *The* rather than just starting with The as per _names starting with the word "The"._ Shouldn't it be `The%`?